# React, styled-components - Display cursor: pointer; on page if menu open?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a `styled.div` for displaying page content underneath a navbar.  The mobile size page has a button that unveils a nav menu `onClick`, and I have a click handler for the page component so if the user clicks on the page content (`PageContainer`) while the menu is open, it closes the menu.

Here's the nav component - it's the entry point for the site, and all the pages get rendered below in the `PageContainer` (I'm using `hookrouter`):

```
const Nav = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);
    const routeResult = useRoutes(directions);
  
  // Click handler for the page content area
    const backgroundClickHandler = () => {
        if (isOpen) {
            setIsOpen(!isOpen);
        }
  };
  
  // Click handler for menu toggle button
    const toggleClickHandler = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

    return (
        <Container>
            {/* Mobile menu toggle button ( */}
            <ToggleContainer>
                <button
                    className='fas fa-bars fa-2x'
                    onClick={toggleClickHandler}
                ></button>
            </ToggleContainer>
      {/* Mobile menu  */}
        <NavWrapper>
                    <ul>
                        {routes.map(({ key, href, label }) => (
              <li key={key}>
                                <A href={href} className='nav-route'>
                                    {label}
                                </A>
                            </li>
                        ))}
                    </ul>
                </NavWrapper>
      {/* This is the page content area */}
            <PageContainer onClick={backgroundClickHandler}>
                {routeResult || <NotFoundPage />}
            </PageContainer>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Nav;
```

Here's the `PageContainer styled.div`:

```
const PageContainer = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 16rem;

    @media (min-width: 40rem) {
        position: relative;
        top: auto;
    }
`;
```

How would you recommend I go about adding `cursor: pointer;` to the `PageContainer` if `useState isOpen = true`?

I thought about making another `PageContainer`, e.g. `PageContainerIsOpen`,  that could be used if the menu is open and render each one conditionally via a ternary expression, but I'm afraid it would be very expensive.  Is there a way I can build the condition into the `PageContainer` itself?  Other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass down props to a styled component. For instance you can do something like:

```
const PageContainer = styled.div`
   cursor: ${props => props.isOpen? 'pointer' : 'unset'};
`
```

And call it like:

```
<PageContainer isOpen={isOpen} />
```

Comment: Oh that's perfect! I had noticed props for conditionally setting CSS properties but I didn't know props could pass any info from within the component.   Thank you!